# remove a set of words from a list of text

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to remove a list of words from a list of text but output seems like its not getting removed. Please help me in the removing the text from the list

```
text_list = ['apple is good for health', 'orange and grapes are tasty']
words = ['apple','orange','grapes']
words_format = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|',join(words))
remove_words = lambda y: y.replace(words_format,' ')

new_text = list(map(remove_words, text_list))
```

Expected output:

```
['is good for health', 'and are tasty']
```

Comment: You'll want to use `reduce` here: `reduce(lambda acc, word: acc.replace(word, ''), words, s)` and apply this to every element in `text_list`. See [here](https://www.online-python.com/1ke5fUZPqi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just split the input, filter out the invalid words and then join the results again:

```
[" ".join([word for word in text.split(" ") if word not in words]) for text in text_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) doesn't recognize regular expressions. You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead.

```
import re

text_list = ['apple is good for health', 'orange and grapes are tasty']
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes']
words_format = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words))
remove_words = lambda y: re.sub(words_format, ' ', y)

new_text = list(map(remove_words, text_list))
print(new_text)
```

Output:

```
['  is good for health', '  and   are tasty']
```